# ERC721 Minted NFT not showing on Opensea.io testnet

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, nft, erc721

I run my code on rinkeby etherscan network and it works perfectly. But the image and descriptions are not showing on opensea testnet. I run the /validate/ url it shows `Valid: "false"`.

Here is what I found when I force update on opensea, https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0x668D179B933af761e4732B084290D32B3235C22b/0/?force_update=true

Here is my code:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "./ERC2981ContractWideRoyalties.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract SmoothApe is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable, ERC2981ContractWideRoyalties {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    using Strings for uint256;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    event EmitNFT(address sender, uint256 tokenId);

    uint256 public preSaleTokenPrice = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 public costPrice = 0.02 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
    uint256 public maxMintNft = 10;

    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    string public notRevealedUri;

    bool public paused = false;
    bool public revealed = true;
    bool public presale = false;

    // set 0x7350243981aB92E2A3646e377EBbFC28e9DE96C1 as payable admn wallet
    address payable public adminWallet = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);
    address payable public communityWallet = payable(0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db);
    address payable public t1Wallet = payable(0x78731D3Ca6b7E34aC0F824c42a7cC18A495cabaB);
    address payable public t2Wallet = payable(0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465E7f2);
    address payable public t3Wallet = payable(0x17F6AD8Ef982297579C203069C1DbfFE4348c372);

    // Mapping from token ID to owner address
    mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;



    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol,string memory _initBaseURI, string memory _initNotRevealedUri) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        setNotRevealedUri(_initNotRevealedUri);
    }

    // inherit and override erc165
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override (ERC721, ERC2981Base) returns (bool) {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    // set Royalty value (between 0 and 10000)
    function setRoyalties(address recipient, uint256 value) public onlyOwner {
        _setRoyalties(recipient, value);
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    function mintApe() public payable {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        require(!paused, "Minting is paused");
        require(msg.sender != owner(), "You can't mint ape to admin");
        // require(_mintAmount > 0, "Mint amount must be greater than 0");
        // require(_mintAmount <= maxSupply, "Mint amount must be less than or equal to max supply");
        if(presale == true) {
            preSaleTokenPrice = costPrice;

        }
        require(msg.value >= costPrice, string(abi.encodePacked("Must send at least ", costPrice.toString(), " ether to purchase")));
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) < maxMintNft, "You can only own 11 ape at a time");
        // require(_mintAmount + balanceOf(msg.sender) <= maxMintNft, "You can only own 10 ape at a time");
        // adminWallet.transfer(msg.value);
        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
        emit EmitNFT(msg.sender, tokenId);
        // for(uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++){
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        // _setTokenURI(tokenId, _baseURI());
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        // }
    }

    // admin mint ape to wallet
    function mintApeTo(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        require(!paused, "Minting is paused");
        require(_mintAmount > 0, "Mint amount must be greater than 0");
        require(_mintAmount <= maxSupply, "Mint amount must be less than or equal to max supply");
        for(uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++){
            uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
            _safeMint(_to, tokenId);
            // _setTokenURI(tokenId, _baseURI());
            _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        }
    }

    function getCostPrice() public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return costPrice;
    }
    //  function to set cost of ape
    function setCost(uint256 _preSaleTokenPrice, uint256 _publicTokenPrice) public onlyOwner {
        preSaleTokenPrice = _preSaleTokenPrice;
        costPrice = _publicTokenPrice;
    }
    // set presale to true
    function setPresale(bool _presale) public onlyOwner {
        presale = _presale;
    }
    function reveal(bool _reveal) public onlyOwner {
        revealed = _reveal;
    }
    // pause function
    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        paused = true;
    }
    // set function for setBaseURI and setNotRevealed function
    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setTokenURI(uint256 _tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public onlyOwner {
        _setTokenURI(_tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }

    
    // override tokenURI function
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
        require(tokenId < _tokenIdCounter.current(), "Token ID must be less than the total supply");
        if(!revealed) {
            return notRevealedUri;
        }
        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0 
            ? string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    currentBaseURI, 
                    tokenId.toString(), 
                    baseExtension))
                    : "";
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of NFT i mint:
https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x668D179B933af761e4732B084290D32B3235C22b/0

my ipfs CID:
ipfs://QmaoMZ19zhpC6T4id6jdBP1Qz5dQSmRZMkQZU7Zt8hyFNQ/

Comment: They are showing correctly for me, sir

Comment: I viewed it on another browser and it's working fine. I don't know what could have caused the problem but it's all fine now

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in the right up corner there is a "reload" button, you need to click it to reload the ipfs on opensea

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that I wasn't uploading the images to ipfs correctly because it was visible only to me on my machine. So try to see if the ipfs metadata are correctly formated and are accesible from different devices.

Also you shouldn't just paste your entire contract in. Tt is really hard to answer your question then. Just write out the important sections of the code.